# Using python to find specific pattern contained in a paragraph

Tags: python, data-processing

I'm trying to use python to go through a file, find a specific piece of information and then print it to the terminal. The information I'm looking for is contained in a block that looks something like this:

```
\\Version=EM64L-G09RevD.01\State=1-A1\HF=-1159.6991675\RMSD=4.915e-11\RMSF=1.175e-07\ZeroPoint=0.0353317\
```

I would like to be able to get the information `HF=-1159.6991675`. More generally, I would like the script to copy and print `\HF=WhateverTheNumberIs\`

I've managed to make scripts that are able to copy an entire line and print it out to the terminal, but I am unsure how to accomplish this particular task.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions is to use regular expressions ([regex](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html)) in order to catch the required pattern:

```
import re #for using regular expressions
s = open(<filename here>).read() #read the content of the file and hold it as a string to be scanned
p = re.compile("\HF=[^\]+", re.flags)  #p would be the pattern as you described, starting with \HF= till the next \)
print p.findall(s) #finds all occurrences and prints them
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions is the answer, something like r'/HF.*/'.

Tutorial:- [regex tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Once you have learned regex, it is an indispensable resource.